# Get Value from <select> dropdown list in order to display an image that correspond with the ID of the selected option value

Tags: jquery, ajax

I would like to get get a value form a dropdown list which is generated by looking into the values inside my Database (of course without being redirected to a post page using a submit php, it has to be like a WebApp) I read onlne that I should use Ajax and/or JQuery but I actually don't understand how it works as I learned to code by myself and analysing a lot of scripts.
I hope someone could help me
Farell

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>projet</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css"/>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Molengo' rel='stylesheet'>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div id="header">
      <img style="height:120px;"src="Logo.png"/><h3>Test</h3>
    </header>
    <div id="ZoneB"></div>
    <!--BLOCK CONNECT DB-->
    <?php
      try
        {$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=braceletcustom;charset=utf8', 'root', '');}
      catch (Exception $e)
        {die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());}
    ?>
    <!-- END BLOCK CONNECT DB-->
    <!--INITALIZE VARIABLES-->
    <form id="FormPierres">
    <?php
    $boucle = "0";
    $ID = "0";
    $IDB = "0";
    $NOM = "rien";
    //-- END INITALIZE VARIABLES-->
      //--READ CONTENT FROM "pierres" TABLE AND DISPLAY IT-->
      $reponse = $bdd->query ("SELECT * FROM `pierres`");
      while($DATA = $reponse->fetch())
      {
          if ($DATA['NOM'] != $NOM){
            ?>
            </select>
            <br>
            </div>
            <?php
            ?><div id="liste"><?php
            $ID = $DATA['ID'];
            $NOM = $DATA['NOM'];
            $NDiametre = $DATA['NBDIAMETRE'];
            $boucle = "0";?>
            <img src="pierres/<?php echo $DATA['ID'];?>.png"/><br>
            <?php echo $DATA['NOM'];?><br/><br/>
            <span class="custom-dropdown custom-dropdown--white">
            <select class="custom-dropdown__select custom-dropdown__select--white" onchange="showUser(this.value)" id="<?php echo $DATA['NOM'];?>"><?php
            ?><option selected value="0">Choisir Diamètre&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</option><?php
            goto A;
            }
            elseif ($DATA['ID'] == $ID AND $boucle <= $NDiametre-1 AND $DATA['NOM'] == $NOM){
                A:
                $boucle++;
                echo "TEST";
                ?><option value="<?php echo $DATA['ID'];?>"><?php echo $DATA['DIAMETRE'];?> mm</option><?php
                $ID++;
          }

      }
      $reponse->closeCursor();?>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in reading that Ajax is the easiest way to interact with a database on a single page.

W3Schools has a useful example involving PHP, AJAX and MYSQL:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

More information on Ajax calls can be found in the jQuery API Documentation.
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

A simple example of this can be found below:

```
$.get('/path/to/file.php', function(data){
    console.log(data);
}
```

Your application will perform a Ajax request to your PHP file which is interacting with your database. This PHP file will return the data you want which can then be processed in your return function.

Note that this also can be completed using XML HttpRequest (https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp) however JQuery Ajax is a lot simpler.

Comment: Thank you for your help
I actualy saw the W3schools's page about Ajax but did'nt understood that "q" was the Value who was posted on the PHP file.
Thank you for your help J_C